# dispatch_once vs static

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently writing a helper class for my app. The helper class will return globally accessible variables. I created a simple helper as shown below:

```
@interface MyHelper : NSObject
{

}

+(id) sharedHelper;

+(NSMutableArray *) employers;


+(id) sharedHelper
{
    static MyHelper *sharedHelper = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken,^{

        sharedHelper = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedHelper;
}

+(NSMutableArray *) employers
{
    return _employers; 
}
```

Now I can access the employers like this:

`[MyHelper employers]` and I can also access it like this `[[MyHelper sharedHelper] employers]` What is the benefit for each approach or they they both same.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that employers array is a property of your class MyHelper.

If you call [MyHelper employers] without call [MyHelper sharedHelper] you can get incorrect result (the value of employers array is garbage).

Maybe the best practice here is to use lazy loading in +(NSMutableArray *) employers and get static variable out of +(id) sharedHelper:

```
static MyHelper *sharedHelper = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

+(id) sharedHelper
{
    dispatch_once(&onceToken,^{

        sharedHelper = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedHelper;
}

+(NSMutableArray *) employers
{
    if(!sharedHelper)
        [MyHelper sharedHelper]; 

    return _employers; 
}
```

Comment: In your `employers` class method, you're trying to access the `_employers` ivar directly. I don't think you can do that from a class method. Or are suggesting he make `_employers` a global?

Comment: You're right. I tryed to modify as little as possible the version contained in the question so i suppose that _employers is some sort of static or global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You `employers` class method is referencing `_employers`, which is presumably an instance variable for your class. You cannot do that. Furthermore, even if you did some sloppy workaround, like a global variable, you have no assurances that `_employers` has been instantiated unless the `employers` class method also ensures that the `sharedHelper` is called.

So, a couple of thoughts:

1. You really should have some class property for `employers` (I assume you did, but omitted it for brevity, but let's include it here to eliminate ambiguity):

   ```
   @interface MyHelper : NSObject

   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *employers;

   @end
   ```
2. I presume your `init` method would initialize this `employers` object

   ```
   - (id)init
   {
       self = [super init];
       if (self) {
           _employers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       }
       return self;
   }
   ```
3. Your existing `sharedHelper` method is perfectly fine.
4. If you're going to have an `employers` class method, though, should access the `employers` instance method:

   ```
   + (NSMutableArray *)employers
   {
       return [[MyHelper sharedHelper] employers];
   }
   ```

Having done all of that, your class would look like:

```
@interface MyHelper : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *employers;

+ (id)sharedHelper;
+ (NSMutableArray *)employers;

@end

@implementation MyHelper

+ (id)sharedHelper
{
    static MyHelper *sharedHelper = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken,^{
        sharedHelper = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedHelper;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _employers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (NSMutableArray *)employers
{
    return [[MyHelper sharedHelper] employers];
}

@end
```

That works, but having said that, as a matter of style, I personally wouldn't recommend a class method, `employers`, when you have a getter method for a property of the same name. Seems a little confusing. I would excise that `employers` class method, and stick with the standard getter method that will be synthesized for you, resulting in just:

```
@interface MyHelper : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *employers;

+ (id)sharedHelper;

@end

@implementation MyHelper

+ (id)sharedHelper
{
    static MyHelper *sharedHelper = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken,^{
        sharedHelper = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedHelper;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _employers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And then other code using this `MyHelper` class can simply refer to `[[MyHelper sharedHelper] employers]` themselves.